# use MFC x86 instead of x64?

Tags: c++, mfc, x86, 64-bit

I have 2 questions I could really really use your help with.

I have an MFC application that compiles using Win32 (32bit) x86 settings, meaning I have not targeted for x64 and I dont release it under x64, however when I build a setup using installshield it shows a dependency for Visual C++ MFC 12.0 (x64). This really should be Visual C++ MFC 12.0 (x86) instead.

Now I am wondering:

1- How can I change in the Visual Studio project to reference to MFCx86 instead of MFC x64 so that it compiles with that library instead, in reality they should be the same, however not sure why it's compiling with x64.

2- Can I just remove the reference to MFC x64 in installshield and ship it with MFC x86 instead? would it still work? How would it know what library to use?

I really appreciate your help with this one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to elaborate, I have also set MachineX86 as the target machine, as well as configure everything to be Win32 based instead of x64 in the configuration manager & project properties. However still there is the dependency to MFC x64, Also I am compiling "Use MFC in a Static Library" & Multi-Threaded DLL /MD, appreciate your help! I have read something about the vcxproj file and other files but not sure if that would make any changes as to which reference and dependency to use.

Comment: Your project configuration is broken. If you use MFC in a static library, there should be no dependency on any MFC DLL at all. Unless you link against a (3rd party) library, that has a dependency on MFC itself.

Comment: thanks, I am using other 3rd party libraries, but they are all just .c files, I am pretty sure they dont have any dependency on MFC but I will check again, any reason why even if they did have a dependency why the MFC wouldnt be included in the .exe file itself? Also what could be broken? any ideas? thanks again!